# How to place these 2 arrays inside separate objects and push to the main array in JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash, underscore.js

I have 2 filtered arrays:

```
productsByCategory,
productsByTag
```

so I need to get the following structure:

```
this.filteredProducts = [{
  type: 'Category'
  products: productsByCategory // it's array
}, {
  type: 'Tag'
  products: productsByTag // it's array
}]
```

So this should be the end result. I am using Vue.js and lodash. How can be this achieved in an elegant way?

Comment: Create the structure by typing as you already did.

Comment: As Ori Drori says, you've already written the code you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

A good straight-forward answer can be given if you say the intention behind that structuring otherwise you could just use a method to accomplish that.

```js
{
  data() {
    return {
      productsByCategory: [],
      productsByTag: [],
      filteredProducts: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    groupProducts() {
      this.filteredProducts.push({
        type: "Category",
        products: this.productsByCategory
      });
      this.filteredProducts.push({
        type: "Tag",
        products: this.productsByTag
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you pushing twice?

Comment: you could also push once, separating the parameters with a comma